# How can I run two docker containers using the same port?

Tags: linux, docker, port, mqtt

I am pretty new to docker containers, but I have the following task:

I have a notebook running Ubuntu 20.04 on which I have to run TTS (The Thingss Stack), with it's MQTT broker, and also Mosquitto. The problem is that both of them need to access port 1883 (the default port for MQTT communication).

I would like to know if I there's a way to configure these containers in order for both to have MQTT connection. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: @accdias it could also be an SO solution so it's no definitive to go to another exchange site

Comment: What do you mean by "both containers have to access port 1883"? If they receive this kind of communication through this port you could use NAT to map a different port from the host to the port in the container's network, is that your issue? If not please elaborate more on it

Comment: Not really since it is just a matter of configuration of the containers and that is infrastructure management, not coding.

Comment: Honestly, I can do anything in order to have 2 brokers, one on TTS and a mosquitto, both on the same PC. I am wondering what would be the best solution?

Comment: Add a secondary IP address to the main interface and bind one of the containers to that secondary IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map one to 1883 and one to 1884.

The containers may both expose port 1883, but you can't map both of them to that port on the host machine. So map one to port 1883 and the second to port 1884.

This is what the `-p` option on the docker run command line does.

So for one container do `-p 1883:1883` and the other `-p 1884:1883`

You will just need to tell what ever client you want to connect to the 1884 not to use the default port.

Comment: That's not entirely true. What can't be done is to map the same port on the same IP address of the same host. If you have two or more different IP addresses, you can use the same port without any problems. Check the `publish` syntax: `--publish, -p=ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort | containerPort`

Comment: but most (normal) people only have 1 IP address per machine (excluding loopback)

Comment: Again, not really. And even on the loopback interface you can have as many addresses as you want (2 ^ 24 - 2, in fact).

Comment: OK, now we are splitting hairs on interfaces vs IP addresses. I stand by my original statement, most people have 1 IP address per interface and have 1 active interface at a time, but feel free to add a answer with more details if you want.

Comment: I'm not arguing in any way :-)  and I prefer to not add an answer since I'm confident the question is off-topic in SO.